# activejdbc update in clause is not working

Tags: java, activejdbc

I want to update multiple records using activejdbc

```
Person.update("name = ?, last_name = ?", "name in ?", "Steve", "Johnson", "jagadeesh,varma,jampana,vikash");
```

no error, but nothing is updated in db

Comment: The `update` method returns the number of rows updated, could you please tell us the return of your call.

Comment: Which database are you using? I think the problem is related with the `in` clause, take a look at this: http://javalite.io/in_clause

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related with the `in` clause.
You are passing "jagadeesh,varma,jampana,vikash" not "('jagadeesh','varma','jampana','vikash')" as required on the [in](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx) clause

This solution should solve your problem:

```
Person.update("name = ?, last_name = ?", "name in ('jagadeesh','varma','jampana','vikash')", "Steve", "Johnson");
```

[More details](http://javalite.io/in_clause)

Comment: I checked here it is ok. I believe your record is 'Jagadeesh' and not 'jagadeesh' so it would be `Person.update("name = ?, last_name = ?", "name in ('Jagadeesh','Varma','Jampana','Vikash')", "Steve", "Johnson");`

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem of the ActiveJDBC framework, but rather something that is not supported by JDBC standard. Please, see this page for more information: 
http://javalite.io/in_clause

You will need to concatenate strings:

```
List names = Util.list("jagadeesh","varma","jampana","vikash");
List<Person> people = Person.update(name = ?, last_name = ?", "name IN ('" + Util.join(names, "', '") + "')", "John", "Doe");
```

Unfortunately this may open a possibility for SQL injection attack if you are building a web app - so be careful.

Comment: thanks ipolevoy, i did'nt get your answer, in the above code you are not updating any thing. is there any other way to update specific fields using  in clause

Comment: basically, the same answer given by @vladwoguer, which I upvoted too